# Goroutine executes a few seconds but stops

Tags: go

I'm currently learning golang and I've tried the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    go routine()
    go routine2()

    fmt.Println("I am not interrupted by Go routine :)")

    for {

    }
}

func routine() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("hello, world!")
    }
}

func routine2() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("hello, world222")
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I get as output: `"hello, world"` and `"hello, world222"` for a few seconds. However, after a few seconds, I don't get anything anymore however the program is still running.

What's wrong? Why does the program stop displaying `hello, world` and `hello, world222` ?

Comment: infinetly (infinitely?) or for a few seconds ? can't be both.

Comment: There is never a reason to use a busy loop in your code.

Comment: @JimB I know, that is only for testing purposes as otherwise the program exits before goroutines are executed

Comment: @JohnDoe: incorrect code for testing purposes is still incorrect code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because for now (go 1.10) Go's scheduler is not preemptive, and there is no plans to make it so.

What this means is that Go's scheduler can stuck in some rare cases, where that there is an infinte loop doing nothing Go's schedule feels like to interupt. And that includes an empty infinite loop.

To block the goroutine for test, use `select{}` instead of `for {}`.

References:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11462

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10958

Answer (score 0):

You are burning CPU with the empty `for` loop
Use `select` instead `for`

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go routine()
    go routine2()

    fmt.Println("I am not interrupted by Go routine :)")
    select{}
}

func routine() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("hello, world!")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func routine2() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("hello, world222")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Your code is okay, never stops but it's correct.

Comment: Nope. The only thing that fixes the problem is the `select{}` in the main func. No `time.Sleep` is ok.

Comment: I see, why did you add a Sleep() function on the goroutines?

Comment: To avoid CPU burning and see and understand better what happens.